# Python regex - reduce redundancy in patterns?

Tags: python, regex, functional-programming

We're writing a Python script to parse application logfiles.

Most of the logfiles will follow a similar format:

```
09:05:00.342344343 [DEBUG] [SOME_APPLICATION] [SOME_FUNCTION] Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet
```

We have a variety of regex expressions to parse the different sorts of loglines that come through, and strip out the relevant fields into Python regex groups (timestamp, log level, originating app/function, as well as fields in the payload).

I've stored each of these regexes in a dict:

```
foobar_patterns = {
    'pattern1': re.compile(r'blahblahblah'),
    'pattern2': re.compile(r'blahblahblahblah'),
}
```

However, there is obviously quite a fair bit of overlap between each pattern - the regex expressions to extract the timestamp, log level etc are shared.

Is there a way to remove this redundancy? Can you build up the difference regex strings somehow from a common template?

Extension - I'm looping through lines in the file, and then for each given line, looping through each compiled regex expression. Then based on that, there are different functions to handle each case - e.g. if we detect a certain type of message, we may need to search ahead three lines to find some ther line, and extract a field from that.

I was thinking of storing a function in the foobar_patterns dict as well, and then when we hit a match, executing on that.

Is that a Pythonic way to do things?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MONTH = r'(?P<month>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)'
DAY = r'(?P<day>\d{2})'
TIME = r'(?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<minute>\d{2}):(?P<second>\d{2})'
SPC = r'\s'
HOST = r'(?<host>\w+)'
PREFIX = SPC.join(MONTH, DAY, TIME, HOST)
foobar_patterns = {
    'pattern1': re.compile(PREFIX + r'\s(?<payload>blahbla hbla h blah)'),
    'pattern2': re.compile(PREFIX + r'\s(?<payload>bla h blahbla hblah)'),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Haave you considered Parsing twice? E.g. first step extract `timestamp`, `level`, `Application`, `Function` and then parsing the payload? You might have to do some caching, maybe first build a list of parsed log objects and then evaluate the sperated log messages (makes it easier to skip 3 lines ahead (like you mentioned might be necessary) without the need to parse lines twice)

Alternatively you can use string concatination:

Pseudocode:

```
basePattern = "\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[\w+\]"
foobar_patterns {
 'payloadPattern1':'asdf',
 'payloadPattern2':'asdff',
}
for patternKey in foobar_patterns:
    foobar_patterns[patternKey] = re.compile(basePattern + foobar_patterns[paternKey])
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use a "grammatic" approach when building complex regular expressions. First you define your "grammar" as a dict, for example:

```
logfile_grammar = {
    'spaces':  '\s+',
    'mname':   '(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)',
    'month':   r'\d\d',
    'day':     r'\d\d',
    'year':    r'\d{4}',
    'date':    '(?P<date>($year-$month-$day)|($day $spaces $mname $spaces $year))',
    'payload': '(?P<payload>.+)',
    # more stuff
    'line':    '$date $spaces $payload'
}
```

As you see, `$xxx` on the right refer to the keys (symbols) on the left. Then you translate this grammar into a regular expression:

```
def compile_grammar(grammar):
    g = dict(grammar)
    for _ in range(16):
        c = False
        for k, v in g.items():
            w = re.sub(r'\$(\w+)', lambda m: g[m.group(1)], v)
            if w != v:
                g[k] = w
                c = True
        if not c:
            return g
    raise ValueError('too much recursion')

g = compile_grammar(logfile_grammar)    
line_regex = re.compile(g['line'], re.X)
```

Now, `line_regex` is one single regular expression that can handle any possible log line.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lot of overlap, consider using a single regular expression that extracts all the fields at once:

```
r'(?P<timestamp>\w*) \[(?P<level>\w*)\] \[(?P<application>\w*)\] ...'
```

When matching with this regex, the resulting match object will have a `groupdict()` from which you can pull the named groups.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import re

line = '09:05:00.342344343 [DEBUG] [SOME_APPLICATION] [SOME_FUNCTION] Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet'

ts_pattern = r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+'
name_pattern = r'\[\w+\]'

patterns = [('timestamp', ts_pattern),
            ('log_level', name_pattern),
            ('app_name', name_pattern),
            ('func_name', name_pattern),
            ('payload', '.*$')]

line_pattern = r'\s+'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % (name, pattern) for name, pattern in patterns)

regex = re.compile(line_pattern)

matches = regex.match(line)

print matches.groupdict()
```

This will give you:

```
{'timestamp': '09:05:00.342344343', 'log_level': '[DEBUG]', 'payload': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet', 'func_name': '[SOME_FUNCTION]', 'app_name': '[SOME_APPLICATION]'}
```